# Distribution of sum of order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Im trying to solve the following problem:

"Let $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ be independent $Exp(1)$-distributed random variables, and let $X_{(k)}$ denote the corresponding k-order variable. Determine the distribution of $\sum_{k=1}^3 X_{(k)}$."

I know that $f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)}}(y_1,y_2,y_3) = 3!f(y_1)f(y_2)f(y_3)$ when $0<y_1<y_2<y_3$. Where $f$ is the density of the $X_i's$.

My idea was to make the transormation 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
X_{(1)}\\
X_{(2)}\\
X_{(3)}
\end{pmatrix}=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
U\\
V\\
W\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then I think $f_{U,V,W}(u,v,w)=3!f(u-v-w)f(v)f(w)$ for $0<u-v-w<v<w$.

To get the density of $U$ I can integrate w.r.t  $v$ and $w$ but I'm not sure what limits to put in the integral. If anybody could help me out on this I'd be very greatful!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, it is actually that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 X_{(i)} = \sum_{i=1}^3 X_i
$$
where $\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i$ follows $\mathsf{Gamma}(3, 1)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions)).

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand! But I should get the same answer by inetgrating $f_{U,V,W}$ w.r.t $v$ and $w$?